# default rails text area value with simple_form

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, textarea, simple-form

I want to set a default text_area value.

```
<%= f.text_area :observations, :value => partner_setting.observations, :class => "tinymce", :rows => 4, :cols => 120 %>
```

But the field displays the same default text after replacing the content and returning to edit.
How can I reset it after create?

Thanks!

Comment: instead `value` use `placeholder`.

Comment: @Зелёный the text area is rendered empty when using :placeholder.

Comment: what you mean *reset it after create* ? Can you provide example input and output or more info?

Comment: @Зелёный I want the text field to output the (if) modified value instead of the default one, after submitting the form and going back to edit it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the text to persist on focus, try this instead:

```
<%= f.input :message, input_html: { value: 'hello hello'} %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need a placeholder, otherwise it will erase your content.

```
<%= f.text_area :observations, :placeholder => partner_setting.observations, :class => "tinymce", :rows => 4, :cols => 120 %>
```

Comment: placeholder empties the value on focus

Answer (score 0):

thanks for suggestions, I solved this issue through a helper method which takes 2 params (passing them from the view):

```
def offer_settings offer, key
  offer.send(key) || offer.partner_setting.send(key)
end
```

view:

```
<%= f.text_area :offer_greeting, :value => offer_settings(@offer, :offer_greeting), :class => "tinymce", :rows => 4, :cols => 120 %>
```